# Remove spaces between a special character and any other character Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which gets a person name (Firstname Lastname) from the 4th line in a text file then create a folder with this name concatenated to "-ID" using the below script.

The problem is that the name is stored in a file with lots of spaces after the last name, so when I create a folder the folder is named `"Firstname Lastname         -ID"` for example.

Any advice how I can remove the empty spaces between the lastname and the "-" character, so that the folder will be named `"Firstname Lastname-ID"`?

```
SET id=abc111
set "xprvar="
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in ('type "C:\My folder\name.txt"') do if not defined xprvar set "xprvar=%%i"
set foldername=%xprvar%"-"%id%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use `Call` with the `%*` metavariable, which would ignore any trailing spaces.

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "id=abc111"
For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=* UseBackQ" %%A In ("C:\My folder\name.txt") Do Call :Sub %%A & GoTo :Break
GoTo :EOF
:Break
Rem Your commands here
MD "%foldername%" 2>Nul
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "foldername=%*-%id%"
GoTo :EOF
```

*You'll also note that this works with names such as `Jean-Claude Van Damme`*

**Edit**
The following modification should cater for the possibility that your text file is not a standard ASCII text file using Windows CRLF line endings.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "id=abc111"
For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=*" %%A In ('Type "C:\My folder\name.txt"') Do Call :Sub %%A & GoTo :Break
GoTo :EOF
:Break
Rem Your commands here
MD "%foldername%" 2>Nul
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "foldername=%*-%id%"
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Did you test it? I've tried this but it didn't work and the folder is not created http://pasteall.org/990898 any advice?

Comment: @Tak, no, I didn't test it, _I do not often have access to a Windows PC_, although with a basic script such as this I have no need to. What you should perhaps have done was test using my code, instead of introducing typo's/errors. First thing to do is fix your error on line `3`, `C:\My`. After doing that Change line `7` to `MD "myfolder\%foldername%" 2>Nul`.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, it's because of pasteall interpreting it as python :/ kindly find the code here https://pastebin.com/eJPA5tPm

Comment: @Tak, I'm assuming that either the server location is not available at that time or the user does not have the correct privileges for writing to it. What is the output if you change `MD "\\myserver\myfolder\%foldername%" 2>Nul` to `Echo MD "\\myserver\myfolder\%foldername%" 2>Nul`? And/Or does it create the directory along side your batch file if you change it to `MD "%~dp0%foldername%" 2>Nul`?

Comment: I tried but the command window closes so I can't see the output, not sure why although there is a pause?

Comment: @Tak, change `@Echo Off` to `@Echo On`, then open a command prompt window, `CD` or `PushD` to the directory holding your batch file and type its name, you should be able to then capture all of its output.

Comment: I just tried Echo On and it only prints the commands executed not the value of foldername

Comment: @Tak, I'm not coming to your computer, _unless you cover my travel and associated costs_, so please provide the output!

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://pasteall.org/pic/c0f471d9586e6e774749ad2891afe21f of the output to this script https://pastebin.com/rY2ZQAHd

Comment: @Tak, you need to verify that there is a text file named `name.txt` in `C:\My Folder` and that it has content, because the `For` loop has not found one! If there is one there and it has content please provide that content.

Comment: yes, there is definitely is as shown here http://pasteall.org/pic/bb6aaf5caa8c337b076ce1d74bd01a75

Comment: I have just quickly borrowed a Windows PC, and tested your exact script in the above link against a new file containing the same content and saved from notepad, _as in your image_, as `name.txt` to `C:\My folder`. It works exactly as intended. The only possible issue I can see is that your text file isn't an ASCII text file using Windows CRLF line endings, where did it come from? and if it isn't as I've stated, try reverting back to using `Type`: `For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=*" %%A In ('Type "C:\My folder\name.txt"') Do Call :Sub %%A & GoTo :Break`

Comment: This was the problem. Now it's working fine. Thank you

Comment: I've added an Edit to my answer to cover that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to test had you posted sample data

```
for /F "tokens=1,2skip=3 delims= " %%i in ('type "C:\My folder\name.txt"') do if not defined xprvar set "xprvar=%%i %%j"
```

But  what happens with such names as "Jean-Claude Van Damme"

Comment: Isn't Van Damme known for breaking things? `:D`